# How to write a limit function in Scala?

Tags: function, scala, return-value, return, limit

After wondering about certain bugs in my first Scala application, I discovered that my limit function was not quite working ... at all!

So here was my **first attempt**:

```
  def limit(x : Double, min: Double, max : Double) = {
    if (x < min) min;
    if (x > max) max;
    x;
  }
```

*It always returned `x`!*

My **second attempt** looked like this:

```
  def limit(x : Double, min: Double, max : Double) : Double = {
    if (x < min) return min;
    if (x > max) return max;
    x;
  }
```

and it worked.

So my question: why are `min;` and `max;` from the first example basically no-ops, and `x;` is not?
And is my second attempt good Scala?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've written a generic version of this (which I had called `clamp`), which looks like this:

```
// NOTE: This will still do some boxing and unboxing because Ordering / Ordered is not @specialized.
@inline def clamp[@specialized(Int, Double) T : Ordering](value: T, low: T, high: T): T = {
  import Ordered._
  if (value < low) low else if (value > high) high else value
}
```

In Scala, the result of an expression is the last value mentioned in that expression. The result of the if-expressions in your first attempt is thrown away, because each if-expression is followed by another expression. Your second attempt is ok but you could do it with `if ... else` like in my example. You could write yours like this:

```
def limit(x: Double, min: Double, max: Double): Double =
  if (x < min) min else if (x > max) max else x
```

Comment: I was wondering whether it was possible to do a generic version. Thanks for posting yours, I did not know about the "Ordering" trait!

Comment: Be careful with this, pulling in the implicit infix operators from typeclasses like `Numeric` and `Ordered` can cause a 6x slowdown, even with specialisation.  You're better off using `Ordering` via a named implicit instead of a context bound, then using the `Ordering.min` and `Ordering.max` methods

Comment: @Kevin Yes that's why the NOTE comment is in my code; unfortunately the specialization doesn't really help because `Ordering` and `Ordered` aren't specialized...

Comment: Boxing is relevant, but I was referring more to the use of `<` and `>`, which invoke an additional implicit conversion (`mkOrderingOps` from `Ordered`)

Comment: AFAIK, there is not @specialization benefit, because of `Ordering`.

Answer (score 14):

Or even:

```
val limited = lower max x min upper
```

`max` and `min` have the same precedence and associate left, so no parens are needed

Comment: For people who might be confused, `lower` is the variable with the lower bound, `upper` is a variable with the upper bound, `x` is the variable being limited, and `max` and `min` are methods of the Int class.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't specify `return` explicitly, then return value is the result of the last expression. In your first example your last expression is `x;`, so it would be returned in any case. If you want to return different value, then you can use `if/else if/else`:

```
def limit(x : Double, min: Double, max : Double) = 
    if (x < min) min
    else if (x > max) max
    else x
```

In this case `if/else if/else` is treated as single expression that returns single value.

You can also use pattern matching like this (it's also single expression):

```
def limit(x : Double, min: Double, max : Double) = x match {
    case x if x < min => min
    case x if x > max => max
    case _ => x
}
```

I don't think that your second example can be described as "good scala". In such simple case it just complicates the whole thing and has 3 points of return (instead of single point of return). It also adds more unnecessary boilerplate.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just:

```
import math.{min, max}
val limited = min(max(lower, x), upper)
```

or

```
val limited = (lower max x) min upper
```