# Is a @specialized Ordered possible?

Tags: scala, autoboxing

I want to implement a "clamp" function for numeric types: `Int`, `Double`, `Float`, etc.

(If it works for other things, like Strings, that's fine too, but that is not my goal.)

[This](http://www.scala-notes.org/2011/04/specializing-for-primitive-types/) demonstrates that specialization with an implicit `Ordering` still boxes/unboxes the parameters.

But it never conclusively established whether there was a solution, perhaps by not accepting an arbitrary `Ordering`.

Will this work?

```
def clamp[@specialized A <% Ordered[A]](low: A, high: A)(value: A) =
  if(low > value) {
    low
  } else if(high < value) {
    high
  } else {
    value
  }
```

Or does the `<%` cause boxing and unboxing?

If it does, is writing a separate function for each primitive type my only recourse?

---

EDIT: There is a question with similar intent -- [How to write a limit function in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199627/how-to-write-a-limit-function-in-scala) -- though it asks for neither generics nor specialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can essentially achieve this with scala macros, though you won't be doing it for `Ordering`. Instead, you'll have a function that works for any class that implements a form of the `<` or `>` functions. It will do as much work as it can at compile time, and fail **while compiling** if no acceptable implementation of less-than or greater-than is found.

First you need to define a Macros object, to contain the implementation:

```
// macros.scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

object Macros {
  def clamp[A](c: Context)(low: c.Expr[A], high: c.Expr[A])(value: c.Expr[A]): c.Expr[A] = {
    import c.universe._

    val tree = 
      q"""
        val lowResult = $low
        val valueResult = $value
        var hasValue = false
        var result = valueResult

        if (valueResult < lowResult) {
          hasValue = true
          result = lowResult
        }

        if (!hasValue) {
          val highResult = $high
          if (valueResult > highResult) {
            result = highResult
          }
        }

        result
      """

    c.Expr(tree)
  }
}
```

**Note:** Based on **Karol S**'s suggestion, I've rewritten the macro to evaluate its arguments as little as possible. If the inputs for `low`, `high` or `value` are expensive, it will only evaluate `low` and `value` once. `high` will only be evaluated if the value was not found to be `low`. This relies on some vars, but the mutable state is contained entirely within the body of the macro, and is safe to ignore when calling.

Once written, the macro can be referenced by a normal function in the outside code:

```
// main.scala
import scala.language.experimental.macros

object Main {
  def clamp[A](low: A, high: A)(value: A): A = macro Macros.clamp[A]

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val int = clamp(0, 10)(20)
  }
}
```

This produces the following code when compiled with -print:

```
package <empty> {
  object Main extends Object {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val int: Int = ({
        val lowResult: Int = 0;
        val valueResult: Int = 20;
        var hasValue: Boolean = false;
        var result: Int = valueResult;
        if (valueResult.<(lowResult))
          {
            hasValue = true;
            result = lowResult
          }
        else
          ();
        if (hasValue.unary_!())
          {
            val highResult: Int = 10;
            if (valueResult.>(highResult))
              result = highResult
            else
              ()
          }
        else
          ();
        result
      }: Int);
      ()
    };
    def <init>(): Main.type = {
      Main.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

This avoids boxing, though (like @specialized) it will increase the size of your compiled code a bit, by actually inserting the if-statement directly into the code wherever it's used. It also needs to create some temporary variables and do a Boolean check to prevent multiple-evaluation of inputs, but these should be very low impact. It works with both literals and runtime values, as long as it knows the type (which it can almost always infer).

Comment: Won't this macro evaluate its arguments multiple times?

Comment: @KarolS Correct. I updated the answer with a version that evaluates arguments once only (and skips evaluating the `high` input altogether, if possible). It bloats the code a bit, but nicely handles cases where your inputs are expensive functions. Thanks for the input. It could probably be further optimized to detect if the inputs are literals, and actually do the clamping at compile time, though I don't expect that would be the typical use case.

Answer (score 2):

Boxing still occurs.

`<%` means "convertible via implicit conversion", which in this case means an additional implicit parameter of type `A => Ordered[A]`. In order to call `<` method, the code has to wrap the number into a `Ordered[A]` object, in case of primitives these are classes `scala.runtime.Rich***`. Specialization is unable to guess that `<` for integers or doubles is something more specific than that.

Furthermore, `A=>Ordered[A]` will also need boxed inputs, since `Function1` is not specialized for cases `primitive=>reference`, only `primitive=>primitive`.

The boxing will therefore happen twice.

Compiling with `-print` yields this:

```
<specialized> def clamp$mIc$sp(low: Int, high: Int, value: Int, evidence$1: Function1): Int = 
if (evidence$1.apply(scala.Int.box(low)).$asInstanceOf[math.Ordered]().>(scala.Int.box(value)))
  low
else
  if (evidence$1.apply(scala.Int.box(high)).$asInstanceOf[math.Ordered]().<(scala.Int.box(value)))
    high
  else
    value;
```

`Int.box` boxes the integer into `java.lang.Integer`, `evidence$1.apply` unboxes it and boxes it again into `scala.runtime.RichInt`.

I suggest specialising the code by hand.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected I'd have to do that. C++ templates really shine in these situations.